# unique constraint violated (ORA-00001) in concurrent insert

Tags: concurrency, oracle11g, primary-key, unique-constraint

I have a procedure that is called from concurrent transactions:

```
//Some actions here

INSERT INTO table1
                (table1_id, table1_val1, table1_val2, table1_val3)
              VALUES
                (gettablenewid('TABLE1'), val1, val2, val3);

INSERT INTO table1
                (table1_id, table1_val1, table1_val2, table1_val3)
              VALUES
                (gettablenewid('TABLE1'), val1, val2, val3);
INSERT INTO table1
                (table1_id, table1_val1, table1_val2, table1_val3)
              VALUES
                (gettablenewid('TABLE1'), val1, val2, val3);
//some other actions
```

Function gettablenewid code (id_table stores PKs for each table):

```
create or replace
    function        GetTableNewId(tablename in varchar2)
      return number is
      PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
      Result number;
    cursor c1 is SELECT ig.id_value+1 id_new
                              FROM id_table ig
                              WHERE ig.table_identifier = tablename
                              FOR UPDATE of  ig.id_value;
    begin
    for c1_rec in c1 loop  
      UPDATE id_table ig
         SET ig.id_value = c1_rec.id_new
       WHERE current of c1 ;
       Result:=c1_rec.id_new;
    end loop;
    commit;
      return(Result);
    end GetTableNewId;
```

Occasionally insert statement fails with ORA-00001 for table1_id, I can't undestand why it happens.

Comment: +1. SELECT FOR UPDATE and AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION should have taken care of concurrent sequence increments. Of course, the safer and simpler way is to just use a global sequence and not care about gaps in the id.

Comment: I don't see an error, so maybe it's in what you didn't post. Are you sure there is a unique constraint on the table_identifier column of id_table, or could there be two id_table rows for TABLE1? Are you sure table1_id is the column whose unique constraint is being violated, or are there other UNIQUE constraints which might have caused this error?

Comment: @ScottLamb May be the problem not in what I've posted, I'll continue search for an answer... But I'm sure that the error was ora-00001 for table_id constraint and I'm sure that in table 'id_table' there is one row for 'TABLE1'. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So, as Scott Lamb said there is no error in code. I found another process that modified id_table concurrently for table_identifier = 'TABLE1'. Thanks to all for your help.